# Where can I find X-01 power armor pieces?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been playing Fallout 4 for quite a while now and I haven't got any X-01 power armor pieces yet. I've only got the helmet from the brotherhood ship. I'm level 32 and I haven't got one set yet.

I've checked the following locations: 35 Court, Federal Surveillance Center K-21B in the Glowing Sea, the pond around Jamaica Plain and Nordhagen Beach. What I found was T-51, T-45 and T-60. Where can I find X-01 pieces scattered around the map?